# Visualizing two datasets in one scatterplot matrix in d3 with different colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatterplot matrix code in D3 that I want to visualize two datasets in that same scatterplot matrix (svg) but with different color of datapoints.

Right now when I click the update button the old points get removed and the new ones from Data2 are plotted. But I want the old ones to not be removed and instead plot the new datapoints from Data2 in a different color.

The function has this `svg.selectAll("g").remove();` which removes the old svg, but if I comment this line the update function doesn't work at all.

```js
var Data = [{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2,
    "z": 1.5
  },
  {
    "x": 2,
    "y": 1.5,
    "z": 1
  },

  {
    "x": 5,
    "y": 6,
    "z": 3
  },
  {
    "x": 4,
    "y": 8,
    "z": 5
  },
];
var Data2 = [{
    "x": 10,
    "y": 8,
    "z": 9
  },
  {
    "x": 11,
    "y": 12,
    "z": 13
  },

  {
    "x": 14,
    "y": 14,
    "z": 2
  },
  {
    "x": 15,
    "y": 10,
    "z": 10
  },
];

function updateMe() {
  scatterplotmatrix(Data2);
}
var width = 660,
  size = 250,
  padding = 40;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([padding / 2, size - padding / 2]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([size - padding / 2, padding / 2]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", size * 3 + padding)
  .attr("height", size * 3 + padding)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding / 2 + ")");

function scatterplotmatrix(data) {
  var domainByTrait = {},


    traits = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) {
      return d !== "name";
    }), //don't return name
    n = traits.length;

  traits.forEach(function(trait) {
    domainByTrait[trait] = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d[trait];
    });
  });

  xAxis.tickSize(size * n);
  yAxis.tickSize(-size * n);

  svg.selectAll("g").remove();

  svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
    .data(traits)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + (n - i - 1) * size + ",0)";
    })
    .each(function(d) {
      x.domain(domainByTrait[d]);
      d3.select(this).call(xAxis);
    });

  svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
    .data(traits)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + i * size + ")";
    })
    .each(function(d) {
      y.domain(domainByTrait[d]);
      d3.select(this).call(yAxis);
    });


  var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
    .data(cross(traits, traits))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "cell")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (n - d.i - 1) * size + "," + d.j * size + ")";
    })
    .each(plot);

  // Titles for the diagonal.
  cell.filter(function(d) {
      return d.i === d.j;
    }).append("text")
    .attr("x", padding)
    .attr("y", padding)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    });

  // cell.call(brush);

  function plot(p) {
    var cell = d3.select(this);

    x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
    y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);

    cell.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "frame")
      .attr("x", padding / 2)
      .attr("y", padding / 2)
      .attr("width", size - padding)
      .attr("height", size - padding);



    cell.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d[p.x]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d[p.y]);
      })
      .attr("r", 4)
      .style("fill", "blue");
  }
}

function cross(a, b) {
  var c = [],
    n = a.length,
    m = b.length,
    i, j;
  for (i = -1; ++i < n;)
    for (j = -1; ++j < m;) c.push({
      x: a[i],
      i: i,
      y: b[j],
      j: j
    });
  return c;
}

scatterplotmatrix(Data);
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px 'ProximaNova';
  padding: 10px;
}

.axis,
.frame {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line {
  stroke: #ddd;
}

.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.cell text {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.frame {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #aaa;
}

circle {
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

circle.hidden {
  fill: #ccc !important;
}

.extent {
  fill: #000;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="scatterplot_Matrix"></div>
<button onclick="updateMe()">Update</button>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

P.S: [Here](https://codepen.io/gty996/pen/eYpbrXQ?editors=1111) is the code in codepen.

Comment: So do you want to have to click the button to see the second set of data alongside the first set, or do you just want to see them both together from the get go?

Comment: @RyanDabler thank you for your comment. Either one is fine, but yeah would be better I think if I see them both together from the get go, but in different color.